# Counting a Digit in a String of Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input('Enter a number: ')
b = input('Enter a digit between 0 and 9: ')
p = int(0)
t = int(0)
while p <=len(a):
    if a[p] == b:
    t += 1
    p += 1
else:
    p +=1

print ('The number', b, 'appears', t, 'times')
```

I need to count the number of times a digit appears in a sting of numbers. This code if telling me that the string index is out of range, which I understand means it is out of the while loop but I don't know how to make it within range.

Comment: So, just to be sure: I'm assuming this is a class assignment, so using the `count` method is off-limits? Because otherwise, `t = a.count(b)` would solve the whole deal.

Answer (score 0):

First, your indenting is a bit broken.  Hopefully that's just a copy/paste issue.

The "out of range" issue is coming from your `while` condition.  Try `while p < len(a)` instead of `while p <=len(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your indenting is a bit off. If I fix the indenting inside the `while` loop and change `<=` to `<` (a length `n` array goes from `0` to `n - 1`), your program becomes this:

```
a = input('Enter a number: ')
b = input('Enter a digit between 0 and 9: ')
p = int(0)
t = int(0)
while p < len(a):
    if a[p] == b:
    t += 1
    p += 1
else:
    p +=1

print ('The number', b, 'appears', t, 'times')
```

and accomplishes your desired behavior.

A note on the code: you're writing Python, not assembly. You can use a `for` loop to count occurrences in a string much more succinctly:

```
a = input('Enter a number: ')
b = input('Enter a digit between 0 and 9: ')
t = 0
for d in a:
    if d == b:
        t += 1

print ('The number', b, 'appears', t, 'times')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem this way:

```
a = input('Enter a number: ')
b = input('Enter a digit between 0 and 9: ')

count = sum([digit == b for digit in a])
print('The number', b, 'appears', count, 'times')
```

Unpacking what's happening:

Let's say `a = '155628'` and `b = '5'`

- `[digit == b for digit in a]` is a list comprehension that will iterate through every digit (which is a string) in the number `a`. It will return a list containing `True` and `False` elements if that digit matches the digit provided in `b`: `[False, True, True, False, False, False]`
- `sum()` counts the number of non-falsey values in the list, in this case 2